# Get and build a date in controller from a select_date and select_time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this form in my view:

```
    <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>
        <%= select_date(@min_date, { :order => [:day, :month, :year], start_year: @start_year, end_year: @end_year }, style: "width: auto;") %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Time</td>
      <td>
        <%= select_time(@min_date, {}, style: "width: auto;") %>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

And I'm getting it in my controller like this:

```
unless params[:date].nil?
  params[:event][:date] = DateTime.new(
    params[:date][:year].to_i, params[:date][:month].to_i,
    params[:date][:day].to_i, params[:date][:hour].to_i,
    params[:date][:minute].to_i, 0
  )
end
```

The problem is that entering an example date like this:
[image]

Is setting the hour and minute but not the date:

```
(rdb:369) pp date
Sat, 09 Feb 2013 16:37:00 UTC +00:00
```

I don't know what I'm missing... I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figure it out, setting the prefix attribute in the select_date and select_time helpers in my view, like this.

```
    <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>
        <%= select_date(@min_date, { :prefix => "date", :order => [:day, :month, :year], start_year: @start_year, end_year: @end_year }, style: "width: auto;") %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Time</td>
      <td>
        <%= select_time(@min_date, { :prefix => "time" }, style: "width: auto;") %>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

And building the date, as follows:

```
unless params[:date].nil?
  params[:event][:date] = DateTime.new(
    params[:date][:year].to_i, params[:date][:month].to_i,
    params[:date][:day].to_i, params[:time][:hour].to_i,
    params[:time][:minute].to_i, 0
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do this in the contoller. Provided that this is a datetime field in the database, rails will do all of this automaticly. You can change the format when you fetch it from the database.

Comment: But I need to set the date before save the event to the database, because I have to compare it with another dates and anyway only the the time is being set properly, not the date